# How to run shell command in Dockerfile after docker container starts up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Based on [bitnami-docker-jasperreports](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-jasperreports) I'm trying to copy some files and folders to  jasperserver folder deployed in tomcat, first i added a COPY and ADD instructions within my Dockerfile and both of them can not work with the deployed folder because it's not already present or it gets overridden after copying them to it, then I tried to add and ENTRYPOINT, RUN and CMD instructions and all of them have failed.
here is my Dockerfile with Entrypoint instruction

```
FROM bitnami/jasperreports:7.8.0
ADD . /bitnami/
ENTRYPOINT [ "cp", "/bitnami/jrs/.", "/bitnami/tomcat/data/jasperserver/WEB-INF/" ]
```

NB: `jrs` folder is in the same folder as my Dockerfile

Edit: I've added a volume to the container to see jasperserver folder in my machine but i found that the link is broken, however when I acces it trough docker bash it seems fine.
[image]

docker bash:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging this by getting a shell into the container? You can do this by removing the `ENTRYPOINT` command and running `docker run -it CONTAINER bash` and examining where your `jrs` folder is.

Comment: @tentative yes I tried it and `jrs` folder is within `bitnami` folder

Comment: What's the error you get when you try to run/build? I think your error is not recursively copying files. Can you try with the `-r` flag?: `ENTRYPOINT ["cp", "-r" , "/bitnami/jrs", ... ]`

Comment: @tentative I don't get any error when i build the image, but when i run the container I get this error `cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/bitnami/jrs/.'`

Comment: @tentative when I added the `-r` flag I get this error `cp: cannot create directory '/bitnami/tomcat/data/jasperserver/WEB-INF/': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Ah, then it seems like `/bitnami/tomcat/data/jasperserver/WEB-INF/` doesn't exist.

Comment: @tentative Nope `/bitnami/tomcat/data/jasperserver/WEB-INF/` exists but I think the proble is related to permissions but how can I solve it